# Pygame Asteroidz program issues

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So, I'm making an Asteroidz game in Pygame (this is my first time using Pygame) and am trying to make this intro screen ("Press space to start"), and when the user inputs space they are entered into the game, but it won't work. The image file is just a white triangle on a black background (Do I need to specify the directory if it's in the same location as the program?)

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour = (255, 255, 255)
        self.x = 390
        self.y = 290
        self.shape = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/John Birch/Desktop/Python/playerimg.jpg')

    def Input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += dist


class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold', 60)

    def Start(self):
        start = menu.font.render("Press space to begin!", 1, (255, 255, 255))
        return start

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player()
menu = Menu()
pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroidz')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
                while True:
                    player.Input()
                    screen.blit(player.shape, (player.x, player.y))
                    clock.tick(40)
                    pygame.display.update()
        start = menu.Start()
        screen.blit(start, (190, 280))
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: use only one `while` loop and when user click `space` then leave this loop and then create second `while` loop only for game. See http://imgur.com/MT7tZ4s

Comment: render text only once - in `__init__` - and later blit it in `while` loop. Use `lower_case` names for functions and `CamelCase` names only for class names. See: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: read about `pygame.Rect()` - it is usefull to keep object size and position. And to check collision with other object or with mouse.

Comment: Cheers furas, updated it to a better design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the line `elif event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:`, use if instead of elif. Then, on the next line, why do you use `while True` again? You're already in a loop. Also, move `clock.tick` to the main loop. And why are you calling `pygame.display.update` twice? Remove the first call. You're placing way too much stuff inside `if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:`

Next, create a function to draw text :

```
def RenderText(Text, Font, Target, X, Y, R, G, B):
""""Text , font, target surface, X, Y, 
and color (RGB)."""
RenderedText = Font.render(Text, True, (R, G, B))
Target.blit(RenderedText, (X, Y))
```

Then, scrap the `Start` method from your `Menu` class, and remove `start = menu.Start()` and `screen.blit(start, (190, 280))` from your loop. Instead, to draw text, use the function you've just defined :

```
fontFreesandBold = pygame.font.SysFont('freesandbold', 35) # Size
```

in your loop :

```
RenderText('Press space to begin!', fontFreesandBold, screen, 190, 280, 255, 255, 255)
```

I understand *why* you placed tons of code inside the `if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:`. You thought that that code would only be run *after* space had been pressed. But no, it will only be run ***when*** space is pressed, so here, I've remastered your entire code for you; and commented everything I've done. Read through it, and I'm sure you'll get your errors : (For now, I removed the player image loading/drawing. Test the code first and then add them back by uncommenting them)

```
import pygame
import sys

from pygame.locals import * 
# The above line imports all the local pygame variables

def RenderText(Text, Font, Target, X, Y, R, G, B):
    """Text , font, target surface, X, Y, 
    and color (RGB)."""
    RenderedText = Font.render(Text, True, (R, G, B))
    Target.blit(RenderedText, (X, Y))




class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colour = (255, 255, 255)
        self.x = 390
        self.y = 290
        # self.surface = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/John Birch/Desktop/Python/playerimg.jpg')
        # Surface is more concise than shape, which could mean other stuff

    def Input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[K_DOWN]:
            self.y += dist
        if key[K_UP]:
            self.y -= dist
        if key[K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist
        if key[K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += dist

        print('Player X/Y ', self.x, self.y) # To show that it's working


class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.level = 0




pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) # Make the screen white
pygame.display.set_caption('Asteroidz')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
player = Player()
# menu = Menu() # I commented this out because it's currently useless


fontFreesandBold = pygame.font.SysFont('freesandbold', 35) # Size


isGameStarted = False

# You don't need if name == main
# because your code is a single file
while True:
    clock.tick(40)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                isGameStarted = True # Now the game has begun!

    print('Game started : ', isGameStarted)

    if not isGameStarted: # Will the game has not begun
        RenderText('Press space to begin!', fontFreesandBold, screen, 190, 280, 
                255, 255, 255)   
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) # As an example, the screen will turn green when the game starts

    if isGameStarted: # Now this code will run forever, once space has been pressed once
        # Place all game code here
        # PS try the arrow keys !
        screen.fill((15, 200, 20))
        player.Input()
        # screen.blit(player.surface, (player.x, player.y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort on answering this :). Really means a lot. Thank you

Comment: Use `elif` when checking for event types. It can only be one of the different types so it's unnecessary to check the other conditions if the previous have evaluated True. Also, use `lowercase_and_underscore` for variable/function names, and `CamelCase` for classes. It makes it easier to differentiate between them. Otherwise, great answer! +1

Comment: @S_Zizzle Glad I could help :)

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Yeah now that I think about it, you're right about the `if/elif` (I don't know what I was thinking). As for my naming style, I guess I use this method because I think it looks cleaner. In the end, it all boils down to personal choice. Thanks for your input though :D

Comment: It can be good learning the conventional coding styles for each programming language since programming collaborations/careers will require you to write code in specific styles to simplify communication between programmers. Also, whenever someone needs to read your code (in order to give feedback, tips, etc.) it'll make it easier for them. You're right that it is your choice in the end, but it might be good to at least think about, even if you might ultimately disagree. Happy coding!

Comment: @TedKleinBergman You're absolutely right. Adopting a proper naming convention is essential to collaboration. But I'm currently 14 and therefore am not working at Microsoft yet. However, it seems as if it would be wise to begin now. I should do it (but I'm gonna have to reformat _all_ my current scripts...) Thanks!